# Msmq error code -1072824294

Tags: msmq

I am using MSMQ and  java client.  When I try to receive messages, I get

hr <-1072824294>  . Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are getting MQ_ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW error . check your code please

Comment: public String Receive() { String dataresult = null; try { checkOpen(); System.out.println("receive"); Message msg= Msmq.receive(2000); // timeout= 2000 ms System.out.println(" ==> message: " + msg.getMessage()); dataresult =msg.getMessage(); System.out.println(" label: " + msg.getLabel()); } catch (MessageQueueException ex1) { System.out.println("Receive failure: " + ex1); } return dataresult; } Any ideas on how to fix this . Many thanks

Comment: Sorry , I am having trouble formatting this code. It has worked earlier. I am getting 
 (hr=unknown hr (-1072824294))
I am using Java client . The data is about 2000 bytes.  I am new to this and any help in fixing will help. Thanks

Comment: send only Hello WOrld and see if your program receives it fine

Comment: That just means that the data you are sending is bigger than a message size , can you try printing it before you send and check the size

Comment: I sent messages bigger than just "Hello World" eg:"Hello World" concatenated 20 times and the receive function works fine too. The data packet size will be max 2048 bytes . Is it possible to receive it ?

Comment: Actually my problem is not solved. I am not able to receive the messages ( about 2048 bytes) still.

Comment: well this is certainly a bug in code as MSMQ has a 4 MB limit per message

Comment: But I am trying to get just 2048 bytes which is much less than 4 MB

Comment: what is the actual string you are trying to send ?

Comment: The data is coming from a device and varies. max size is 2048 bytes